# Dependent sections in openmp

Tags: openmp

I'm wondering if there is a way to include a dependency between sections in OpenMP? I know that there is a possibility to do that when using tasks but is there a way using sections? Say that I have the following case:

```
#pragma omp parallell sections
{
    #pragma single
    {
        if (....) {
            #pragma section
            {
                a = A(); // <- Takes much more time than B and will be parallellized further within A
            }
            #pragma section
            {
                b = B();
            }
        }
        ...
        #pragma section (dependent on b?)
        for (...) {
            c = C(b);
        }
    }
}
```

What would be the best way to make sure that the last section is executed after 'b' is available?

Comment: I suppose that the 'solution' of just putting the line `c = C(b)` inside the second of your sections arises from an inessential feature of your constructed example.  Perhaps an example which demonstrates the necessity of section dependencies would help the thinking here.

Comment: Why cannot you use tasks?

Comment: The reasons why I'm hesitant to use tasks is the compiler support for later versions of the OpenMP standard. Visual studio for instance do not seem to support tasks.

Comment: Regarding why not putting c = C(b) inside the second section (or the other way around) is due to that I was hoping to keep the flow of the program as close as possible to the single threaded version and maintain the readability of the code. There are also some issues within the "..." that needs special attention. I'll see if I can update the example to make that clear.

Comment: Christian, if you restrict yourself to MIcrosoft's compiler there is no reasonable solution. The right answer (as Zulan is implicitly suggesting) is to use a modern compiler and tasks. I believe that both gcc and clang work on Windows, are gratis, and have modern OpenMP support. The Intel compiler is another option if you are prepared to pay, or qualify for a free license https://software.intel.com/en-us/qualify-for-free-software  [FWIW I work for Intel]